# redis error memory > 'maxmemory' but im using less than half of the max

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I'm trying to load some large csv files into redis. I get the memory > 'maxmemory' error. However, when I check the usage of my database, it says

```
used_memory_human:4.63M
used_memory_peak_human:9.26G
```

I don't understand the disconnect there. I'm trying to upload about 5.6gb and it shouldn't come close to 9. Also, the db was completely empty when I started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are going on -

1. The size of your CSV may not have a direct relationship to the memory taken by redis. How much memory redis consumes depends on what data structures you are using.
2. While you are writing to redis, redis is also trying to take a full backup of the data to disk. To take a backup, redis forks the existing process and does a copy on write. Now if you are not writing frequently, the forked process does not consume much memory. But you are writing aggressively - so you end up requiring almost double the memory.

Disable RDB persistence during your bulk load and then load your data. Once you have loaded the data, manually take a backup using the `bgsave` command. Then you can restore your original backup configuration.